# Exact search with ElasticSearch using EdgeNGram

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic for searching with greek and latin characters.My main problem is that I can't do exact searches.I am using edgeNgram filter on indexing, but I would like to control its min and max at search time according to my word length.For example if I type "titanox" I will firstly get "ΤΙΤΑΝΙΟΥ" and secondly "TITANOX".Here is my index creation :

```
var response = client.CreateIndex(index, s => s
            .Settings(s1 => s1
.NumberOfShards(5)
.NumberOfReplicas(5)
.Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters(t => t.IcuTransform("greeklatin", it => it.Id("Greek-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC")//
.Direction(IcuTransformDirection.Forward)) //
.IcuTransform("latingreek", lg => lg.Id("Greek-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC")
.Direction(IcuTransformDirection.Reverse))
.EdgeNGram("greekedge", ed => ed.MaxGram(7)
.MinGram(1)
.Side(EdgeNGramSide.Front))
.Stop("greekstop", sw => sw.StopWords())
.Lowercase("greeklowercase", gl => gl.Language(Language.Greek.ToString()))
.KeywordMarker("greekkeywords", gk => gk.Keywords(""))
.Stemmer("greekstemmer", gs => gs.Language(Language.Greek.ToString())))
.Analyzers(a1 => a1
.Custom("greek", t => t.Tokenizer("standard")
.Filters("greekedge", "greekstop", "greeklowercase", "greekkeywords", "greekstemmer", "greeklatin")))))
.Mappings(m => m.Map(type, mt => mt.Properties(c => c.Text(c1 => c1.Name("id").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c2 => c2.Name("brand").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c3 => c3.Name("service").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c4 => c4.Name("servicegroupdesc").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c5 => c5.Name("servicecategorydesc).Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c6 => c6.Name("partscategory").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c7 => c7.Name("partsid").Analyzer("greek"))
.Text(c8 => c8.Name("partsdesc").Analyzer("greek"))))));
```

and here my search

```
   var response = client.Search<Cars>(n => n
                        .Index(index)
                        .Type(type)
                        .Query(m => m.MultiMatch(q => q
                            .Analyzer(analyzername)
                            //.MinimumShouldMatch("100%")
                            .Query("*" + searchWord + "*")
                            .Fields(f=>f.Field(fieldsForSearchList[0]))
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(0))))
                        .Size(searchSize)
                        .From(0)
                        .TrackScores(true)

                    );
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your question? It's going to be more difficult for anyone to read and help the way it is

Comment: I think the problem is generated by using edgeNgram but, how can it get solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that may can help is adding to this query a new query for boosting the word that users type.This can achieve more exact searches.